# What is FOIL and how is it done?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My Algebra teacher was explaining to the class about creating a trinomial using FOIL. What is it, and how is it done?

Comment: Also wiki: [Foil Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method).

Comment: Forget about Foil, it is for little old school marms, study the distributive law.

Comment: Why was this question down voted?

Comment: I dont know why this was downvoted, but there is a systematic program by a small number of users to downvote and close questions not meeting their "standards".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FOIL is a mnemonic for how to multiply thing in the form $(a+b)*(c+d)$

$$(a+b)*(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$$

This is you add up the **F**irst terms (ac) , **O**utside terms (ad) , **I**nside terms (bc), and **L**ast terms (bd)

Its just another way to simplify this type of multiplication.

Comment: How is my simple explanation of a simple mnemonic worth 3 upvotes when my more in depth analyses are ignored on other problems? #stackexchangeproblems

Comment: More people can understand the clarity of this explanation.

Comment: @mathtastic Thats a good point, but as a reasonably advanced math student, I shall choose to ignore it.

Comment: Did I mention that my highest rated answer of all time has to do with explaining what a percent means? 17 upvotes for that one.

Comment: Welcome to the club!

Comment: (Dry my tears with my various certificates for math skills)